# How to check for the existence of a null object in a nested object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

Say for example if I have a 3 level deep javascript object

```
{CONN_INFO: {CFGSwitch: {412: {}}}}
```

How can I write a function that determines if it is nested?
And secondly, how can I then convert the empty object `{}` to a string such as `"{}"`

Comment: If you really mean JSON, your syntax is incorrect. JSON requires all property names to be inside "double quotes".

Comment: `{}` is _not_ a `null` value. It is an empty object. If you `alert({}==null)` you will get `false`.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for that. I've updated the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I write a function that determines if it is nested?

For all keys of the current object, check its type, if JSON then nesting is present.

> And secondly, how can I then convert the empty object {} to a string such as "{}"?

If you encounter a nested JSON object, check for its key length using Object.keys(currentJSONObj).length, if 0 then this is an empty JSON. So re-assign "{}" to the key which had empty JSON object at first place.

Comment: Would I have to use a recursive function for the second part? Any idea how I could write it? I've now got a function to check how deep the nesting is.

Comment: Yes.. Recursive function is the answer. Call it for every key within the object, if the value of that key is JSON again, recur!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate and check `Object.keys(current_obj).length`